# How to assess normality of a single item variable before running ANOVA in an experiment?

Tags: normality-assumption

In my experiment, I have 3 dependent variables, each measured through a single item. I want to assess their normality before proceeding to MANOVA. These three variables failed the Shapiro-Wilk test. Need help!
I will run MNOVA for these three dependent variables. These variables are measured on 7-point Likert Scale. I want to see how different leadership styles (conditions) affect the intrinsic motivation in case of no reward and extrinsic motivation incase of monetary and social reward. Where intrinsic and extrinsic motivation are measured through single items.

Comment: Why do these variables need to have normal distributions? It would help if you could provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish, specifying your dependent and independent variables and the comparisons you wish to make.

Comment: Do you have three *independent* variables? If you have three dependent variables, you probably should not be running an ANOVA. You say you have an "item", are these likert items (ir oedipal ratings)? If so, how could it be possible for them to be normal?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will run MNOVA for these three dependent variables. Yes, these are measured on 7-point Likert Scale. I want to see how different leadership styles (conditions) affect the intrinsic motivation in case of no reward and extrinsic motivation incase of monetary and social reward. Where intrinsic and extrinsic motivation are measured through single items.